# Running an .exe inside a Docker Windows container

Tags: .net, docker

I followed this short tutorial: [Containerize a .NET core app](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/docker/build-container?tabs=windows)

Basically, my Dockerfile contains:

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/runtime:5.0
COPY bin/Release/net5.0/publish/ App/
ADD ./hello.exe App/hello.exe
WORKDIR /App
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "NetCore.Docker.dll"]
```

Note that hello.exe is a simple C++ "hello world" that I've created locally with gcc and then I've copied inside the container.

The .net app "NetCore.Docker.dll" works just fine. However, I enter the container with:

```
docker run -it --rm --entrypoint "cmd.exe" test-image
```

.... and then I want to run hello.exe. This doesn't work and all I can see is an error code: -1073741515 (after I run echo %ERRORLEVEL%).

So what am I missing inside my Windows container in order to run simple a .exe ?

Thanks,

Greetings,

```
Sorin
```

Comment: What target architecture did you build the .exe for?

Comment: Windows 10, 64 bit, Intel core i7

Comment: By default, the `5.0` tag will give you a Nano Server image when targeting Windows containers.  Perhaps your EXE has some dependency that doesn't exist in Nano Server.  Instead, you could try targeting Windows Server Core.  To do that you'd need to replace `5.0` with `5.0-windowsservercore-ltsc2019`.

Comment: @MattThalman I did that, but I have exactly the same issue inside the Docker container:


C:\App>helloworld.exe


C:\App>echo %ERRORLEVEL%

-1073741515